# Compiling MySQL Connector with Visual Studio 2015 Win64

Tags: c++, mysql, c, visual-studio-2015, redefinition

After creating a solution with cmake, I am being put face to face with 1400 errors in Visual Studio during build.
The main problem is, it seems no one compiles the connector, and just uses the precompiled library for their projects, more so on Windows.
Here are some of errors, it seems timespec is being redefined one more time, first of all in ,and then a second time in my_global.h, errors and definitons below.

So the question is, how the hell do I fix 1400 errors?

Or at least, some advice how to get rid of redefinition would be GREAT!

time.h
     #ifndef _CRT_NO_TIME_T
     struct timespec
         {
            time_t tv_sec;  // Seconds - >= 0
            long   tv_nsec; // Nanoseconds - [0, 999999999]
         };
     #endif
my_global.h

```
 struct timespec {
    union ft64 tv;
    /* The max timeout value in millisecond for native_cond_timedwait */
    long max_timeout_msec;
 };
```

Error   C2011   'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition (compiling source file C:\Users\DDubinin\Downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\mysys\my_mess.c)  mysys   c:\users\ddubinin\downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\my_global.h 660

Error   C2039   'tv': is not a member of 'timespec' (compiling source file C:\Users\DDubinin\Downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\mysys\my_malloc.c)   mysys   c:\users\ddubinin\downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\my_global.h 681

Error   C2227   left of '->tv' must point to class/struct/union/generic type (compiling source file C:\Users\DDubinin\Downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\libmysql\authentication_win\handshake.cc)   auth_win_client c:\users\ddubinin\downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\my_global.h 681

Error   C2227   left of '->max_timeout_msec' must point to class/struct/union/generic type (compiling source file C:\Users\DDubinin\Downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\libmysql\authentication_win\plugin_client.cc) auth_win_client c:\users\ddubinin\downloads\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-src\include\my_global.h 682

Comment: Actually, I downloaded the source for MySQL Connector C++ and built the sources on my PCs.  Remember, you must take care that the entire project is 64-bit or entire project is 32-bit.  Use `Dependency Checker` to verify DLLs.

Comment: I suggest downloading the source code from the MySQL site and not GitHub.

Comment: Forgot to clarify, I need MySQL Connector/C, not C++.

Comment: And the github link is a mirror from MySQL site for those people, who would like to look at the code, but won't spend their time downloading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll close this issue, managed to compile the source with an older ,VS2013 x64, version of Visual Studio, and CMake 4.3.1 ...

It seems, the new changes in Visual Studio 2015 are breaking the C connector source code, I hope that MySQL team will fix this in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

i used mysql server code(i.e. mysql-5.7.13.zip) and compiled the MySQL Connector/C from it.

Answer (score 0):

What motivated me to compile this code in vs 2015 is when I compiled mysqlcppconn 1.1.8, I got the error:

```bash
error LNK2038:mismatch detected for `_MSC_VER`:value '1800' does not match value '1900'
```

the `1800`,`1900` indicates the version of vs used.

```
MSVC++14.0 _MSC_VER == 1900 (Visual Studio 2015)
MSVC++12.0 _MSC_VER == 1800 (Visual Studio 2013)
MSVC++11.0 _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012)
MSVC++10.0 _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010)
MSVC++9.0 _MSC_VER == 1500 (Visual Studio 2008)
MSVC++8.0 _MSC_VER == 1400 (Visual Studio 2005)
MSVC++7.1 _MSC_VER == 1310 (Visual Studio 2003)
MSVC++7.0 _MSC_VER == 1300
MSVC++6.0 _MSC_VER == 1200
MSVC++5.0 _MSC_VER == 1100
```

I searched and discovered that it indicates my `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` downloaded from mysql was compiled using VS 2013, and it causes error in VS 2015.

I acctually followed this guide, and it worked fine for me.

> http://nov11.github.io/jekyll/update/2017/04/24/compilemysqlcppconnector1.1.8.html

My os is windows 10 x86

To summarize, Follow the steps:

- git clone mysqlcppconn source code and checkout the desired version

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
  git checkout 1.1.8
  ```
- download boost and mysql-server-code locally, and modify the `CMakeLists.txt` so the compiler can find the library

  In that case, my boost version is `boost_1_64_0`, and mysql is `mysql-5.6.26-win32`. It can be downloaded here:https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.6/mysql-5.6.26-win32.zip

  modify `CMakeLists.txt`, add lines:

  ```
  SET(BOOST_ROOT "C:\\boost_1_64_0")
  SET(MYSQL_DIR "C:\\mysql-5.6.26-win32")
  SET(MYSQL_VERSION "5.6.26")
  ```
- cmake:

  ```bash
  mkdir build && cd build
  cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A win32 -DMYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=yes ..
  ```
- solve the `snprintf link error`:

  comment out the `define snprintf _snprintf` line in `my_config.h` in mysql-server-include code
- generate lib files:

  ```bash
  cmake --build <your-build-folder-path> --config Release --target mysqlcppconn -j 4 --
  cmake --build <your-build-folder-path> --config Release --target mysqlcppconn-static -j 4 --
  ```

Comment: Tks for the advice and I have modified my answer to a more complete one.