# Compiling mysql connector using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I know the topic has been discussed here [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091321/compiling-mysql-connector-with-visual-studio-2015-win64), but then the person asking closed the question him self because he could compile using older version of VS. This is however not an option for me since I have to use VS2015.

I read in the MySQL documentation that it should now support VS2015 and the changes made there. However, I get the same kind of errors as reported earlier regarding timespec and other things.

If anyone solved this, a post here would be great!